# Interrogate API until no results left

Tags: php

I am working with an API at the moment that will only return 200 results at a time, so I am trying to run some code that works out if there is more data to fetch based on whether or not the results have a `offsetCursor` param in them as this tells me that that there are more results to get, this `offsetCursor` is then sent a param in the next request, the next set of results come back and if there is an `offsetCursor` param then we make another request.

What I am wanting to do is push the results of each request into a an array, here is my attempt,

```
   function get_cars($url, $token)
   {
    $cars = [];
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization: Bearer " . $token
        )
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if($err) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $results = json_decode($response, TRUE);
        //die(print_r($results));
        $cars[] = $results['_embedded']['results'];
        if(isset($results['cursorOffset']))
        {
            //die($url.'&cursor_offset='.$results['cursorOffset']);
            get_cars('https://abcdefg.co.uk/service/search1/advert?size=5&cursor_offset='.$results['cursorOffset'], $token);
            //array_push($cars, $results['_embedded']['results']);
        }
    }

    die(print_r($cars));
}
```

I assume I am doing the polling of the api correct in so mush as that if there is a cursor offet then I just call the function from within itself? But I am struggling to create an array from the results that isnt just an array within and array like this,

```
[
   [result from call],
   [resul from call 2]
]
```

what I really want is result from call1 right through to call n be all within the same sequential array.

Comment: I know it's an aside, but wouldn't a while loop have been easier than a recursive function?

Comment: Saying that, using a loop instead would allow you just just generate a standard PHP array without having to merge returns, or use statics / globals, so maybe not as much of an "aside" as I thought.

Comment: Maybe I am overthinking this, but what would the loop conditions be given that I don't know if there is a cursor offset until I have fetched the API?

Comment: You could use your existing check for the curl request failing to break out of the loop (or set a flag to not repeat).

Answer (score 0):

using a do+while loop, you'll have only 1 instance of `cars` variable, that would work.

Since you're using recursion, when you call `get_cars` inside `get_cars`, you have 2 instances of `cars` variable, one per `get_cars` call.

IMHO, using a loop is better in your case.

But if you still want to use recursion, you should use the result of `get_cars` call, something like this:

```
    if(isset($results['cursorOffset']))
    {
        //die($url.'&cursor_offset='.$results['cursorOffset']);
        $newcars = get_cars('https://abcdefg.co.uk/service/search1/advert?size=5&cursor_offset='.$results['cursorOffset'], $token);
        $cars = array_merge($cars, $newcars);
        //array_push($cars, $results['_embedded']['results']);
    }
```

(and `get_cars` should `return $cars`, instead of printing it with `print_r`)

---

**Edit**: here is an example of, untested, code with a while loop (no need for do+while here)

```
<?php
function get_cars($baseUrl, $token)
{
    $cars = [];

    // set default url to call (1st call)
    $url = $baseUrl;

    while (!empty($url))

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization: Bearer " . $token
            )
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if($err)
        {
            // it was "return false" in your code
            // what if it's the 3rd call that fails ?
            // - "return $cars" will return cars from call 1 and 2 (which are OK)
            // - "return false" will return no car (but call 1 and 2 were OK !!)
            return $cars;
        }

        $results = json_decode($response, TRUE);

        $cars[] = $results['_embedded']['results'];
        if(isset($results['cursorOffset']))
        {
            // next call will be using this url
            $url = $baseUrl . '&cursor_offset='.$results['cursorOffset'];

            // DONT DO THE FOLLOWING (concatenating with $url, $url = $url . 'xxx')
            // you will end up with url like 'http://example.com/path/to/service?cursor_offset=xxx&cursor_offset==yyy&cursor_offset==zzz'
            // $url = $url . '&cursor_offset='.$results['cursorOffset'];

        }
        else
        {
            $url = null;
        }

    }

    return $cars;
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of do+while but ive not used it before, any chance of an example?

Comment: @Udders there you go :)